# Unable to open Facebook C# SDK canvas samples. IIS 6?

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2010, iis, facebook-c#-sdk

Downloaded Facebook C# SDK 5.4.1 from [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/78901).

I've been through the `CS-WinForms` solution which works fine. I'm now trying to open the `CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-JsSdk` and `CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-WithoutJsSdk` solutions but I get the following error in VS 2010:

```
D:\VSProjects\...\CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-WithoutJsSdk.csproj : error  :
The Web Application Project CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-WithoutJsSdk is configured
to use IIS. To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS
components:

  IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility
  ASP.NET

In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account.
```

I'm running on Windows 7 (64 bit) so I really don't want to install IIS 6. Can I just run this solution using the built-in VS Cassini web server that I use for everything else?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently I need to edit the .csproj file by hand. The contents are shown below. Can anyone tell me which changes I need to make?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{7A74691E-66DF-4DAA-B9A7-D5428E13B5A9}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>CS_Canvas_AspNetWebForms_JsSdk</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-JsSdk</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Facebook">
      <HintPath>..\..\Bin\Release\net40-client\Facebook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Facebook.Web">
      <HintPath>..\..\Bin\Release\net40\Facebook.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Default.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Facebook\Default.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Facebook\FacebookLoginControl.ascx" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.6.2.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Facebook\Default.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Facebook\Default.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Facebook\FacebookLoginControl.ascx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FacebookLoginControl.ascx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Facebook\FacebookLoginControl.ascx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FacebookLoginControl.ascx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>1220</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:1220/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the project and change the webserver settings to use cassini.  If you cannot get the project to load at all, then you will need to hand edit the .csproj file and change the web server settings by hand.

Comment: No, I can't get the project to load at all. Please see my update to original question. Can you tell me which edits I need to make?

Comment: I'm not going to hand it to you directly as this is a great opportunity to learn.  Create a new project with cassini settings and save it.  Open the xml for it to see what it should look like, then copy it to the bad .csproj.  Happy coding! _hint: it is in the ProjectExtensions section_

Comment: I know you can. Unfortunately it's part of working with VS IDE, sometimes things have to be done by hand.

Comment: That was easier than I thought. For anyone else looking, it's just a matter of changing the setting to `<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>` and it runs fine. I was afraid I was going to have to start messing with some project Guids. Thanks.